# Posts wont expire

Tags: plugins, multisite, customization, wp-cron

I am having some trouble with scheduling posts to automatically expire (either by deleting or going to draft), every plugin I have tried does nothing and when it reaches the scheduled time nothing happens, which is making me think its probably some simple thing I keep overlooking..

I thought I might be a problem with wp-cron, but I don’t seem to have any trouble setting up a publish date in the future through wordPress.

I have the latest version of Wordpress running, with multi-sites set-up. All plugins were at the latest version available at the moment.

Does anyone have any ideas?? I am running out of things to try...

Thanks in Advance

Tafts

Comment: NOTE: when using the plugin Content Scheduler, in the column for the expiry status the default is (Expiration Disabled) but when I enable it with a date nothing shows up, just a blank space, rather than the expiration date ... not sure if this might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working using the Post Expirator plugin, which also had the same problem, but by adding the following code to each loop right after 'the_post();' it checks the posts status on each page load, it is a temporary solution which seems to work for the moment.

```
// check to see whether post has expired
$expiration = get_post_meta($post->ID, "expiration-date", true);
if ($expiration && (time() > $expiration)) {
    $postSettings = array(
        'post_status' => 'draft'
    );

    wp_update_post($postSettings);
} else {
// normal content goes here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

create for these posts a customfield with the name `expires` and the value is the date for disabling the post.
Use the following code in the Loop of your theme.

```
//Loop-Start
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  $exTime = get_post_custom_values('expires');
  if (is_array($exTime)) {      
  $exString= implode($exTime);
  $seconds = strtotime($exString) - time();
} else {
  $secondes = 1;
}
if ($seconds > 0) {
  echo "<h2>";
  the_title();
  echo "</h2>";
  the_content();
}
endwhile;
endif;
```

This code wont delete or drafting the posts. But you don't see it in the front. Perhaos this is a possible solution for your problem?

Comment: I had also tried hard coding it using a similar code and setting the date with custom values, still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I have tried **VA Simple Expires**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/va-simple-expires/

Works pretty well.

Unfortunately **Post Expirator** plugin did not work for me because posts imported via CSV did not expire.

Regarding VA Simple Expires - if you use CSV you should just add couple fields:

- scadenza-enable=1
- scadenza-date=target time (e.g. 2016-04-10
  00:42:00)